# Putting subclass into superclass list

Tags: java

I have an abstract superclass named Troop and a few subclasses with different attributes. I am making a game, in my game I have these buttons to add different troops to the gameboard (the subclasses of Troop). I have this method:

```
public void addTroop(Troop troop)
{
    // Got a list called troopList in my main class
    main.troopList.add(troop);
}
```

Which is supposed to add the different troops to a list in my main function. But since there are differnet troops, megaTroop, fastTroop etc.. this gets messed up because the list won't take all the different types. The button is calling this addTroop method. I know it fails because I have written:

`MegaTroop megaTroop = new MegaTroop();`

and tried to insert it into the list which looks like this: `public List<Troop> troopList;`

I am pretty much in need to somehow cast my subclass as my superclass, any ideas on how to solve this? I hope I gave enough information. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It should work as you describe. Show all your Troop classes, including the Troop super class.

Comment: As long as `MegaTroop` extends `Troop`, your `addTroop()` method isn't the problem. Perhaps you could post the exception that you get?

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Not getting any error in specific, I am testing with JUnit and the test highlights the add method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Troop megaTroop = new MegaTroop();
```

as all your specific types of Troops are Troops anyway. It's called "programming to an interface". This way you can call your method and put your objects into list.